# JQM-$.mobile.pagecontainer not working on internal pages but working on external pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am working on jquery mobile page navigation and facing with strange behaviour of JQM functions.
I have two files main.html,home.html
1.Main.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-enter code here1.4.2.min.css'>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="firstHeader">
    <a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('home.html'{transition:'slide',reverse:true});" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all 
    ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
    <h1>Customer Reg. 1</h1>
    <a href="#secondForm"  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn icon-left">Next</a> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> home.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/cust_reg.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Page 1</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go To Page 2</a>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Page 2</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<a href="#page1" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go Back To Page 1</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> After clicking on "Home" of main.html it redirecting to home.html as
>   expected. but after clicking on "Go To Page 2" of home.html(redirected page) it is not redirecting
>   to "page 2" though it is already in home.html. I have tried to use
>   "$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer" and "$mobile.changePage" but it
>   is not working
>
> Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When using *Single Page Model*, you need to understand that jQuery Mobile loads **ONLY** first `data-role=page` in each file.html. It neglects everything else outside that div.

If you want to mix between *Single Page* and *Multi-Page* Models, you need to navigate to other pages that contain *multi-pages* without Ajax.

For example, navigating from *main.html* to *home.html* with Ajax enabled, jQM will load `page1` div only. If you want to load all pages within *home.html*, you have to disable ajax this way.

```
<a href="home.html" rel="external">Home</a>
```

**Note** that you will lose *transition* effect when Ajax is disabled.