# jquery mobile javascript not being run when sing JQM pageContainer

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to JQM and trying to create a simple login app to learn with.
My login.html page calls the login.php page to verify.  If the user is verified then it returns a 200 and the login.js page moves to the next page which is called "menu.html".  THis is how I am moving to the next page

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "menu.html" );
```

When this page shows it does not execute the javascript inside menu.html?

However, if I press the "refresh" button in my browser to reload the menu.html page, it then runs the javascript.  I need the javascript for menu.html to run when the page is redirected, because the javascript for menu.html does a 2nd level security check using php $_sessions to prevent the user from directly calling menu.html trying to bypass the login process.

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Other references: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21625844/1771795 http://stackoverflow.com/a/24302293/1771795

Comment: I'm good with that...I read the duplicate and it solved my problem by putting the .js files inside the div for the page, instead of placing it in the header.  Thanks.

Comment: You can also add all JS libraries in head of each and every file. They will be loaded once when first page is loaded. This is the recommended approach.